# Adding External GIFs to Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft, emoji

First of all, I am not sure if this is the right forum to ask this. But I will give it a go.

Is there a way to add external GIF files in Teams chat so that they show up in the Emoji section. Like a file path where I drop a GIF file and Teams just picks it up and displays it here maybe.

[image]